# How to resolve a promise inside another promise?

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework-2.0

I have an action which requires to get a list of emails from a remote server. Then I want to use the emails to get a list of emailDomainInformation from another remote server (note that this second piece of info depends on the first). After all this, I want to output data from both servers onto a map and render it onto the page with dust.

I managed to get this to work without the second piece of data by doing it like this:

```
public static Result index()
{
  F.Promise<Email> emailPromise = getEmailPromise(...);
  F.Promise<Result> results = emailPromise.map( new F.Function<Email, Result>()
  {
    public Result apply(Email email)
    {
      Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      data.put("email", email.getAddress());
      data.put("domain", email.getDomain());
      dustRenderer.render(data);
    }
  }
  async(results);
}
```

Now, since I want to make an async call to `getEmailDomainData(email.getDomain());` inside the `emailPromise.map()` method. What do I do with the `Promise<EmailDomain>` object I get back? How do I put that into the `data` map to pass to the `dustRenderer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that essentially does what you need:

```
public static Result social() {
    final F.Promise<WS.Response> twitterPromise = WS.url("http://search.twitter.com/search.json").setQueryParameter("q", "playframework").get();
    final F.Promise<WS.Response> githubPromise = WS.url("https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/playframework").get();

    return async(
            twitterPromise.flatMap(
                    new F.Function<WS.Response, F.Promise<Result>>() {
                        public F.Promise<Result> apply(final WS.Response twitterResponse) {
                            return githubPromise.map(
                                    new F.Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
                                        public Result apply(final WS.Response githubResponse) {
                                            return ok(views.html.social.render(twitterResponse.asJson().findValuesAsText("text"), githubResponse.asJson().findValuesAsText("name")));
                                        }
                                    }
                            );
                        }
                    }
            )
    );
}
```

In this case the two run in parallel but you could move the second `Promise` creation into the handler for the first `Promise`.

Comment: Ah this is helpful. My issue was that the second request depends on the results of the first request, but I also needed to return both the first and the second request in the end. What I ended up doing was: Set up the second request in the handler for the first request. Then do a flatmap of both the first request and the second request and in that handler attach the second request onto the first request and then return the first request as an object. Then in my controller, I can call the first request's getSecondRequest() getter to get the second request.